# How search collection if is more then one?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have datatable with a `categories` table.

I have **two** categories, Category `A` and Category `B`.

I also have a `post` table with `post` assigned to a `category`.

Now I can get all `post` and `category`

```
$posts = PostGroup::whereIn('name', ['A', 'B'])
```

`PostGroup` file has

```
public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dict');
    }
```

Ok now when I call code above and I get the following:

```
Collection {#301 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => PostGroup {#289 ▶}
    1 => PostGroup {#302 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I can do `foreach()` or I can get `posts`

```
$posts = PostGroup::whereIn('name', ['A', 'B'])
$posts[0]->posts->where('group_id', 'A');
```

How can I avoid foreach and search the `$posts` collection to find group `A` something like:

```
$posts->where('group_id', 'A')->posts;
```

Comment: According to your code, $posts are the groups, not the posts.  You're doing a lookup on the PostGroup table..

Comment: cause first i want find all post group by group id and than i would like search collections all $posts instead of $posts[0] what should i do ?

Comment: Firstly, don't name groups $posts, that's confusing.  Secondly, your last example is faulty because $posts is groups, you wouldn't be looking for a group id on a group, would you?  Lastly, you can't use a collection like that, posts would have to be called on each item (not the collection itself), so you have to rethink how you handle this data.  You should probably be querying posts instead of post groups.

Comment: right. Thank You. I will get posts from two groups. This is best simple way.